# How can I stretch a div column vertically to fit its container?

Tags: css

All content is dynamic.

```css
#block {
    width: 500px;
    background-color:#fff000;
    border: thin solid #999;
 
}
#col1{
    width: 300px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    height:auto; 
    overflow: auto;
}

#col2{
    width: 180px;
    background-color:#ffaaff;
    float:right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <div id="col1">

      white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white 

    </div>
      
      <div id="col2">
        pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink 

      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
```

I want the white column to stretch vertically to pair the height of the pink column (reach the bottom yellow border). I prefer not to use absolute or relative displays.

Here is the solution with `display:relative` and `display:absolute`. It works, but gives me other problems in a more complex structure.

```css
#block {
    width: 500px;
    background-color:#fff000;
    border: thin solid #999;
    position:relative;
}
#col1{
    width: 300px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    height:100%; 
    overflow: auto;
    position:absolute;
}

#col2{
    width: 180px;
    background-color:#ffaaff;
    float:right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <div id="col1">

      white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white 

    </div>
      
      <div id="col2">
        pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink 

      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/67uqf/5/ is the solution with display:relative and absolute adds. It brings me other problems in a more complex structure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use absolute/relative?  What *do* you want to use?

Here's a CSS only fix, otherwise background image
http://unnaturalcode.blogspot.com/2012/08/css-recipe-for-making-elements-fill.html

Comment: I said 'I prefer', I only want to solve this issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/67uqf/5/  the solution with display relative/absolute adds.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```css
html, body { height: 100% }

#block {
    width: 500px;
    background-color:#fff000;
    border: thin solid #999;
    height: 100%;
}
#col1{
    width: 300px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    height:100%; 
    overflow: auto;
}

#col2{
    width: 180px;
    background-color:#ffaaff;
    float:right;
}
.clear {
    clear: none
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <div id="col1">

      white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white white 

    </div>
      
      <div id="col2">
        pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink pink 

      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
html, body { height: 100% }

#block {
    width: 500px;
    background-color:#fff000;
    border: thin solid #999;
    height: 100%;
}
#col1{
    width: 300px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    height:100%; 
    overflow: auto;
}

#col2{
    width: 180px;
    background-color:#ffaaff;
    float:right;
}
.clear {
    clear: none
}
```

(I changed your clear DIV and added `height: 100%` to surrounding elements.)

Comment: Well, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/67uqf/4/ Added height to html, body and #block

Comment: This is not the same as version 2 http://jsfiddle.net/67uqf/2/ Yellow box is also extended because of body changes. Version 5 http://jsfiddle.net/67uqf/5/ is what I am trying to get but without display:relative on yellow container and display:absolute in white column 1.  It brings me other problems in more complex structure

Answer (score 0):

Set the element to be stretched and all of its parent containers to `height:100%;`.

For example,

```css
#element_to_be_stretched, html, body {height: 100%}
```